# Error with SQL syntax, FULLTEXT search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have an error in SQL syntax.. Please help me. This is my sql:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST ('+nokia') as Score
WHERE MATCH (NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST ('+nokia')
FROM `produkty`
ORDER BY `TOP` DESC
LIMIT 0, 9
```

This is error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE MATCH (NAZOV, POPIS, CENA) AGAINST ('+nokia') FROM `produkty` ORDER BY `T' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is in the wrong spot

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER ...
LIMIT ...
```